# Does the customization project exist in the database?

Tags: acumatica

Let's say you have a simple customization project, which contains only integration scenarios (Xport), maybe some reports and GIs.  No files, code items, ect.  You publish this custom to the application, and all is well.  Now you wish to see the details of this custom in the database.  I notice the table CustProject.  However, customization project record is not found in the table (search by the Name field).  The screen SM204505 shows that the project is published, but where are the details in the database?
According to T300, the customization data for these types of items are stored in the Db.  It is not applied to the website files or Db schema.  So where are the details in the Db?  There is a purpose I have, to look for the details outside of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should connect some dots if you are just looking for the sql

```
-- Published Projects
SELECT c.* FROM dbo.CustProject c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.CustPublishProject WHERE ProjectID = c.ProjID)

-- Contents of project
SELECT p.Name AS ProjectName, o.* FROM dbo.CustObject o
INNER JOIN dbo.CustProject p ON p.CompanyID = o.CompanyID AND p.ProjID = o.ProjectID
```

Comment: There is something else missing.  I browsed both tables previously, but there is no record with the project name.  I verified the project is published, and I check the correct database.

Comment: are you restricting your query by company? I would think the project would have to be in the query if it is (1) showing in the list of customizations and (2) showing as published.

Answer (score 0):

CustProject is the master table of the customization project and CustObject is the detail table.

Request to list Customization Project Items:

```
SELECT CustProject.Name as CustomizationProjectName, 
       CustObject.Name as CustomizationItemName,
       CustObject.Type as CustomizationItemType,
       CustObject.Content as CustomizationItemFile 
FROM CustProject
LEFT JOIN CustObject on CustObject.ProjectID = CustProject.ProjID
```

[image]

Request for file items added to the customization project file section:

```
SELECT CustProject.Name as CustomizationProjectName, 
       CustObject.Name as CustomizationItemName, 
       cast(UploadFileRevision.Data as varchar(max)) as TextFile, 
       UploadFileRevision.Data as BinaryFile 
FROM CustProject
JOIN CustObject ON CustObject.ProjectID = CustProject.ProjID AND
                   CustObject.Type = 'File'
JOIN NoteDoc on NoteDoc.NoteID = CustObject.NoteID
JOIN UploadFile ON UploadFile.FileID = NoteDoc.FileID
JOIN UploadFileRevision ON UploadFileRevision.FileID = UploadFile.FileID AND
                           UploadFileRevision.FileRevisionID = UploadFile.LastRevisionID
```

[image]